# Is there a simple way to negate a javabean binding expression in Netbeans?

Tags: java, binding, netbeans, javabeans

I have a simple test application where I want to have a clear button that clears the text area.  I want the clear button to be disabled when the text area is empty.  So I created a property in my form called "textEmpty".  This property is updated every time the text area is modified.  I bound this property to the "enabled" property of the clear button and things work great... but wait!  When textEmpty is true, enabled is set to true... I want the reverse.  I'm not interested in this test application functioning correctly... it's just an example.  I'm interested in negating the binding property expression in Netbeans.  Currently the expression looks like:

```
Form[${textEmpty}]
```

How do I negate it?

Please understand that I'm interested in negating the expression.  I know I can just change the property from "textEmpty" to something like "textNotEmpty" and update the logic.  That's not what I'm interested.  I imagine this problem will come up frequently when I use javabeans that I do not have control over the properties, so I want to understand these binding expressions better.

Comment: Have you tried `Form[${!textEmpty}]`?  What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Form[${!textEmpty}]
```

Notice the "!" just before "textEmpty".